# What is the history of the import statement?

Tags: java, python, programming-languages, import

I know of two languages that use `import` statement: Java and Python. And we all know [the `import antigravity` joke](http://xkcd.com/353/).

Which language really introduced this statement? Was it one of the two, or another one altogether? When?

Comment: [import antigravity](http://xkcd.com/353/) - for those - like me - who didn't know it.

Comment: @Andreas: I had already edited the question to link to that :)

Comment: The joke refers to the 'battery included' philosophy, not really on the word import.

Comment: Yeah, but it became some kind of signature statement for 'battery included' philosophy. :)

Comment: Might I suggest that the first language to introduce this statement was... _english_.  When casting about for words to describe a technical thing that is happening, `import` is far from a novel keyword - I could believe any one of the programming languages that use it came about that usage independently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`import` is just one way to specify dependency on some other class/module. Some way of specifying that has been present in many, many languages.

In fact `import` in Java and `import` in Python do two entirely different things:

- In Java `import` only provides the ability to refer to a type (or field/method, if using `import static`) by its short name instead of its fully qualified name. No "module loading" of any kind happens based on an `import`.
- In Python `import` actually loads a module and optionally provides a short name for some (or all) of its members.

Other keywords that do somewhat similar things are `include` in C and `use` in Perl. Many, many languages have some kind of way to specify this kind of dependency, but the technical details vary a lot.

One language with an `IMPORT` statement that predates both Java and Python is [Modula-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-2) (1978) and its successor [Modula-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know C language and its `include`. But I was particularly interested in word 'import' as it's widely used when talking about Python's advantages, often humorously.

Comment: As you can see `import` has been around long before Python. These humorous references to it started with Python, as far as I know.

Comment: I wrote my comment before you edited your answer. Also thanks for editing my question. Now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in the 80ies you would first come across import statements in Extended Pascal and Ada in a somewhat different meaning than what is today's commonly accepted usage.

In ADA you would [pragma] import functions from other languages (typically C).  This was similar to JNI in java or declaring a function living in a dll in VB6.
The same concepts were also introduced in extended Pascal (the namespace import concept in Pascal and ADA was actually relying on a combination of the `with` and `uses` keyword).